# Searching Multiple Strings in pandas without predefining number of strings to use

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there's a more general way to do the below? I'm wondering if there's a way to create the st function so that I can search a non-predefined number of strings?

So for instance, being able to create a generalized st function, and then type st('Governor', 'Virginia', 'Google)

here's my current function, but it predefines two words you can use. (df is a pandas DataFrame)

```
def search(word1, word2, word3 df):
    """
    allows you to search an intersection of three terms
    """
    return df[df.Name.str.contains(word1) & df.Name.str.contains(word2) & df.Name.str.contains(word3)]

st('Governor', 'Virginia', newauthdf)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `np.logical_and.reduce`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def search(df, *words):  #1
    """
    Return a sub-DataFrame of those rows whose Name column match all the words.
    """
    return df[np.logical_and.reduce([df['Name'].str.contains(word) for word in words])]   # 2


df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Virginia Google Governor',
                           'Governor Virginia',
                           'Governor Virginia Google']})
print(search(df, 'Governor', 'Virginia', 'Google'))
```

prints

```
                       Name
0  Virginia Google Governor
2  Governor Virginia Google
```

---

1. The `*` in `def search(df, *words)` allows `search` to accept an
   unlimited number of positional arguments. It will collect all the
   arguments (after the first) and place them in a list called `words`.
2. [np.logical_and.reduce([X,Y,Z])](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) is equivalent to `X & Y & Z`. It
   allows you to handle an arbitrarily long list, however.

Comment: sorry is there an equivalent for 'OR'? if I also wanted to mix in or and and searches, how would i do that?

Comment: There are two ways to handle `OR`. You could combine the the regex patterns with `|`, as behzad.nouri shows, or you could use `np.logical_or.reduce`. It might be easiest, however, to allow the user to enter regex (which might contain `|`), and just use `search` to combine the regex with `np.logical_and.reduce`.

Answer (score 15):

`str.contains` can take regex. so you can use `'|'.join(words)` as the pattern; to be safe map to `re.escape` as well:

```
>>> df
                 Name
0                Test
1            Virginia
2              Google
3  Google in Virginia
4               Apple

[5 rows x 1 columns]
>>> words = ['Governor', 'Virginia', 'Google']
```

`'|'.join(map(re.escape, words))` would be the search pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = '|'.join(map(re.escape, words))
>>> df.Name.str.contains(pat)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is helpful! I like both answers, but i chose the one below because it allows you to input an arbitrarily long list of answers with *words, which i didn't know about. I also didn't know regex worked in str.contains, so that's very useful.

Comment: Is it possible to run contains on multiple fields without using the and operator? pseudo:`'df['Name', 'AnotherField'].str.contains(pattern)`