# searching a string pattern from a Data-frame column in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Continuing my last question in stack [searching matching string pattern from dataframe column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740680/searching-matching-string-pattern-from-dataframe-column-in-python-pandas)

Suppose i have a dataframe

```
 name         genre
 satya      |ACTION|DRAMA|IC|
 satya      |COMEDY|DRAMA|SOCIAL|MUSIC|
 abc        |DRAMA|ACTION|BIOPIC|
 xyz        |ACTION||ROMANCE|DARMA|
 def        |ACTION|SPORT|COMEDY|IC|
 ghj        |IC|ACTIONDRAMA|NOACTION|
```

From the answer of my last question , i am able to search any one genre (ex IC) if independently exist in genre column and not as a part of any other genre string value (MUSIC or BIOPIC).

Now i want to find if ACTION And DRAMA both present in a genre column but not necessarily in particular order and as not part of string but individually.

So i need rows in output  row[1,3,4]

```
 name         genre
 satya      |ACTION|DRAMA|IC|   # both adjacently present
 #row 2 will not come           # as only DRAMA present not ACTION
 abc        |DRAMA|ACTION|BIOPIC|   ### both adjacently present in diff. order
 xyz        |ACTION||ROMANCE|DARMA|   ### both present not adjacent
 ##row  5 should not present as DRAMA is not here
 ## row 6 should not come as both are not present individually(but present as one string part)
```

I tried something like

```
 x = df[df['gen'].str.contains('\|ACTION\|DRAMA\|')]
 ### got only Row  1 (ACTION and DRAMA in adjacent and in order ACTION->DRAMA)
```

Please somebody suggest what can be followed/added here so that i can get what i need here.

Comment: `x = df[df['gen'].str.contains(r'(?s)^(?=.*\bACTION\b)(?=.*\bDRAMA\b)')]`

Comment: you want to return the whole line if action and drama is present?

Comment: or just check if they are just present in the line?

Comment: @JanLeeYu- want to return the rows to another  data-frame.

Comment: what abount the `ghi`? is it really `ACTIONDRAMA` or `ACTION|DRAMA`?

Comment: it is ACTIONDRAMA and it should not come in output as they are not separately present by '|' encolsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with two conditions with AND - `&`:

```
print df
    name                        genre
0  satya            |ACTION|DRAMA|IC|
1  satya  |COMEDY|DRAMA|SOCIAL|MUSIC|
2    abc        |DRAMA|ACTION|BIOPIC|
3    xyz      |ACTION||ROMANCE|DRAMA|
4    def     |ACTION|SPORT|COMEDY|IC|
5    ghj    |IC|ACTIONDRAMA|NOACTION|

print df['genre'].str.contains('\|ACTION\|') & df['genre'].str.contains('\|DRAMA\|') 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: genre, dtype: bool

print df[ df['genre'].str.contains('\|ACTION\|') & df['genre'].str.contains('\|DRAMA\|') ]
    name                    genre
0  satya        |ACTION|DRAMA|IC|
2    abc    |DRAMA|ACTION|BIOPIC|
3    xyz  |ACTION||ROMANCE|DRAMA|
```

Comment: @jezrael-Works..may be a offbit question  i have ... is there a way that i can make this kind of thing dynamic(using for loop or some list comprehension)..Like i want to pass [x,y,z] then for x y z the result should come applying all 3 on a base dataframe(like ACTION AND DRAMA applied in Question). My content  of list should be variable length.

Comment: I think this is [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22624079/2901002) for  your comment question - `np.logical_and.reduce([X,Y,Z])`.

Comment: @jezrael- can you plz help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578530/looping-over-a-dataframe-and-fetching-related-data-from-another-dataframe-panda

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about this answer because I don't have a compiler here but try using this one.

`(\|ACTION|\|DRAMA).*?(\|ACTION|\|DRAMA)`

Hope it helps.