# Print specific rows from dataframe using a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Be advised** I'm doing this in a Function, and I've already referred a pretty good thread.

Here's the python function, the parameter passed is taken from user

```
def recommend(uid):
    ds = pd.read_csv("pred_matrix-full_ubcf.csv")
    records = ds.loc[ds['uid'] == uid]
    for recom in records:
        print recom
```

Data Format:

```
uid iid     rat
344 1189    5
344 1500    5
344 814     5
736 217     3.3242361285
736 405     3.3238380154
736 866     3.323500531
331 1680    2
331 1665    2
331 36      1.999918585
```

Referred:
[this1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas),
[this2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578530/looping-over-a-dataframe-and-fetching-related-data-from-another-dataframe-panda)

Unable to get where I'm going wrong, I'm following *this1* thread and yet unable to get it.

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not getting the error, all I get is 'uid iid rat' on whatever number I give as input

Comment: Tejas, now I understand. Take a look at my answer. You need to call `records.iterrows()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To iterate over your rows, use [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
In [53]: records = df[df['uid'] == query]

In [54]: for index, row in records.iterrows():
    ...:     print(row['uid'], row['iid'], row['rat'])
    ...: 
344.0 1189.0 5.0
344.0 1500.0 5.0
344.0 814.0 5.0
```

---

There's two other possible ways to do select your data. You can use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [4]: query = 344

In [7]: df[df['uid'] == query]
Out[7]: 
   uid   iid  rat
0  344  1189  5.0
1  344  1500  5.0
2  344   814  5.0
```

You can also use [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) function:

```
In [8]: df.query('uid == %d' %query)
Out[8]: 
   uid   iid  rat
0  344  1189  5.0
1  344  1500  5.0
2  344   814  5.0
```

Comment: Hey, I did try them. Yet not successful in it. Here's on what I get.

Comment: `records = ds[ds['uid'] == id]
    for recom in records:
        print recom`  gives output as  `Enter User ID:344
uid
iid
rat`

Comment: @Tejas Your code looks nothing like mine. You should use `for index, row in records.iterrows()`. Did you see my answer?

Comment: @Tejas You didn't even copy it correctly brother. Check my edit. Look at the first code snippet. Please copy it exactly like that. Why are you making a mistake while doing ctrl+c ctrl+v?

Comment: @coldspeed Ok bro, I'll try but I've got to change variables as per Nomenclature I'm using.

Comment: Changing variables is fine, but you are changing the functionality of my code and then telling me it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tejas _**What is "query"**_? What are you passing to it? These issues are simple. It seems you are trying to compare strings and ints, which is wrong. In my example, 'uid' is assumed to be integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148782/discussion-between-tejas-and-cs).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `where()` method on the DataFrame object right away. You can provide the condition to this method as the first argument. See the following example:

```
dataset.where(dataset['class']==0)
```

Which would give the following output

```
        f000001   f000002   f000003  ...     f000102   f000103  class
0      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.080000    0.0
1      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.058824    0.0
2      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.095238    0.0
3      0.029867  0.000000  0.012769  ...    0.000000  0.085106    0.0
4      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.085106    0.0
5      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.085106    0.0
6      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.127660    0.0
7      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.106383    0.0
8      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.127660    0.0
9      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.106383    0.0
10     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.085106    0.0
11     0.021392  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.042553    0.0
12    -0.063880 -0.124403 -0.102466  ...    0.000000  0.042553    0.0
13     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.021277    0.0
14     0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...    0.000000  0.000000    0.0
15     0.000000  0.000000 -0.060884  ...    0.000000  0.000000    0.0

[18323 rows x 104 columns]
```

*(I got rid of the rest of the output for brevity of the answer)*

A huge advantage of using this method over just referencing is that you can additionally replace those values that don't match the condition using the `other` argument, and also perform some operation on the values that match the condition using the `inplace` argument. Basically, you can reconstruct the rows of the your dataframe as desired.

Additionally, because this function returns the a dataframe minus those rows that don't match the condition, you could re-reference a specific column such as

```
dataset.where(dataset['class']==0)['f000001']
```

And this will print the `'f000001'` (first feature) column for you, where the class label is 0.