# Selecting rows of a dataframe that contain all strings from a list of search terms, using str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandads Dataframe where one column ('processed') is a single string containing some pre-processed text of varying length.

I want to search using a list of keywords, of arbitary length, to return only the processed notes for rows where the string 'processed' contains ALL of the elements in the list.

Of course, I can search the terms individually, like:

```
words = ['searchterm1', 'searchterm2']
notes = df.loc[(df.processed.str.contains(words[0])) & (df.processed.str.contains(words[1]))].processed
```

But this seems inefficient, and would require different code depending on the number of search terms I'm using.

What I'm looking for is something like....

```
notes = (df.loc[[(df.processed.str.contains(words[i])) for i in range(len(words))]]).processed
```

Which would include

`"searchterm1 foo bar searchterm"`

but NOT include

`"foo bar searchterm1"`

or

`"searchterm2"`.

But this doesn't work - loc doesn't support the generator object or list as input.

So what is the best way to find a string that contains multiple substrings? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching Multiple Strings in pandas without predefining number of strings to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623977/searching-multiple-strings-in-pandas-without-predefining-number-of-strings-to-us)

Comment: Are you looking for **any** (i.e. at least one) or **all** substrings to match?

Comment: Looking for all to match. Will edit question to clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicates of [pandas dataframe str.contains() AND operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation)

Answer (score 2):

Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,'a', 3],
                   [1,'b', 4],
                   [2,'c', 22],
                   [2,'s', 3],
                   [2,'f', 3],
                   [1,'d', 56]], 
             columns = ['group', 'value', 'value2'])

words = ['two', 'three', 'two']
```

Output:

```
  processed
0       one
1       two
2     three
3   one one
4  two, one
```

I modify your code raw:

```
notes = df.loc[sum([df.processed.str.contains(word) for word in words]) > 0]
```

Output:

```
  processed
1       two
2     three
4  two, one
```